# How to overlap images and store them in new image objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two images,now i want to overlay the images,such that the other image appears on center or left corner of the other image,and then when finally both the images are overlayed i can store it in another new image object,and i want to all  this in code behind only not xaml,how to do this?

```
if (((Grid)sender).Children.Count > 0)
{
    gridBackground = (ImageBrush)(((Grid)sender).Background);
    gridBackImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    gridBackImage.Source = gridBackground.ImageSource;
}

System.Windows.Controls.Image imgRejectIcon;
if (((Grid)sender).Children.Count > 0)
{
    imgRejectIcon = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)(((Grid)sender).Children[0]);    
}
```

Now i want to merge gridBackImage and imgRejection and store it in new image object

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange your two `Image`s in any way that you want and I'll leave that code for you to do (it'd *much* simpler to do in XAML). In WPF, *all* UI controls extend the [`Visual` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx). This is very useful for making `BitmapImage`s from UI controls, when used with the [`RenderTargetBitmap.Render` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, arrange your two `Image` controls into a `Grid`, or other container control, and then you can pass the container control to the `RenderTargetBitmap.Render` method and create an `Image` something like this:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = 
    new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(yourContainerControl); 
PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
{
    pngImage.Save(fileStream);
}
```